# Fredholm alternative and orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, inner-products, orthonormal, compact-operators

The following question relates to the Fredholm alternative:
Let $K:H \rightarrow H$ be a compact linear operator and let $I$ be the 
identity operator.

Notation: $N$ is the nullspace and $R$ is the range.

1.The proof of the first part '$N(I-K)$ is finite dimensional' states the following: If we suppose that $\text{dim}N(I-K) = +\infty$. Then we can find a countably infinite orthonormal basis $\{u_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty} \subset N(I-K)$ where $(u_{i},u_{j}) = \delta_{i,j}$.

How are we guaranteed to find such a orthonormal basis for an infinite dimensional subspace? What result is used? Gram-Schimdt only applies to finite-dimensional spaces if I'm not mistaken.

2.The following is taken from a the proof of another property of Fredholm Alternative proof:
Let us consider $\{v_{k}\}_{k}^{\infty} \subset R(I-K)$ where $v_{k} \rightarrow v$. Then, there exists $x_{k} \in H$ which solve $(I-K)x_{k} = v_{k}$. Since $x_{k}$ can be expressed as a sum of basis vectors from $N(I-K)$ and $N(I-K)^{\perp}$, then we can say there exists $u_{k} \in N(I-K)^{\perp}$ solving $u_{k} - Ku_{k} = v_{k}$.

How does it follow that $x_{k}$ can be expressed as a sum from $N(I-K)$ and $N(I-K)^{\perp}$? Then how does it follow that there exists $u_{k} \in N(I-K)^{\perp}$ solving $u_{k}-Ku_{k} = v_{k}$?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 3):

*Ad* (1): Gram–Schmidt can readily be applied to any countable collection of non-zero vectors. Just remember how Gram–Schmidt orthonormalisation works: you simply replace $v_{k+1}$ with its orthogonal projection onto $\{v_1,\dotsc,v_k\}^\perp$, and then normalise (if non-zero). Now, suppose that $N(1-K)$ is infinite-dimensional, and that $\{v_k\}$ is a countably infinite basis of $N(1-K)$. Then, in particular, all finite linear combinations of the $\{v_k\}$ are dense in the closed subspace $N(1-K)$, but by Gram–Schmidt, these are exactly the same as the finite linear combinations of the output of Gram–Schmidt orthonormalisation.

*Ad* (2): By the basic theory of Hilbert spaces, if $U$ is a closed subspace of $H$, then $H = U \oplus U^\perp$, which means, precisely, that for any $x \in H$, you have (unique) $u \in U$, $u^\prime \in U^\perp$, such that $x = u + u^\prime$. Now, apply this to $x_k \in H = N(1-K)^\perp \oplus N(1-K)$ to get $x_k = u_k + u_k^\prime$ for $u_k \in N(1-K)^\perp$ and $u_k^\prime \in N(1-K)$, and observe that
$$
 v_k = (1-K)x_k = (1-K)(u_k + u_k^\prime) = (1-K)u_k + (1-K)u_k^\prime = (1-K)u_k + 0 = (1-K)u_k.
$$

Comment: Could I ask the reasoning for the line "Then, in particular, all finite linear combinations of the ${v_{k}}$ are dense in the closed subspace $N(I−K)$". How do you know that $N(I-K)$ is closed?

Comment: $N(1-K) = (1-K)^{-1}(\{0\})$, where $\{0\}$ is closed in $H$ and $1-K : H \to H$ is continuous.

Comment: Oh yes I see. One more thing, you said all finite linear combinations of the $v_{k}$ are dense in the closed subspace $N(I-K)$, but if they are basis vectors, are all finite linear combinations of the $v_{k}$ not equivalent to $N(I-K)$, since very vector in $N(I-K)$ is a finite linear combination of these basis vectors? What do you mean that they are dense in the closed subspace? Thanks again.

Comment: Consider the usual orthonormal basis of $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$. Is every sequence in $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$ a *finite* linear combination of basis elements? There's an essential terminological problem here: Hamel bases (which you learn about in basic linear algebra) aren't generally the same as Schauder bases (i.e., bases in the Hilbert space sense), unless your Hilbert space is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Cacic, thanks for your responses. Every vector space has a Hamel Basis, proof using the axiom of choice. Why then is it preferred to find a Schauder base, for some infinite-dimensional vector spaces (eg. Hilbert spaces)? Why are Shauder bases easier to find and work with?

Comment: Unless you're fantastically lucky (e.g., the basis $\{1,x,x^2,\ldots\}$ for $\mathbb{R}[x]$), Hamel bases for infinite-dimensional vector spaces are usually impossible to actually construct, cf. the need to use the axiom of choice to prove their existence in general. On the other hand, as the entire theory of Fourier series illustrates, Schauder bases are both easy to construct and compute with, and really do everything you could ever hope to do with bases in an infinite-dimensional setting.